# Append data wrong in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver           
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import requests
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 

URL = 'https://mergr.com/firms/search/employees?page=1&firm%5BactiveInvestor%5D=2&sortColumn=employee_weight&sortDirection=asc'
driver.get(URL)



email=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#username")
email.send_keys("timgr8@outlook.com")

password=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#password")
password.send_keys("Cosmos1990$$$$$$$")

login=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.btn").click()

 


urls=[]        
product=[] 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
details=soup.select("tbody tr")
for detail in details:

        try:        
                t1 =detail.select_one("h5.profile-title a").text
        except:
                pass
  
        wev={
                'Name':t1,
                }
        
        product.append(wev)
           
page_links =driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h5.profile-title + p a")
for link in page_links:
        href=link.get_attribute("href")
        urls.append(href)
        

for url in urls: 
        
        driver.get(url) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
        try:
                website=soup.select_one("p.adress-info a[target='_blank']").text
        except:
                website=''
        
        data={
                'website':website
        }
 
        product.append(data)
                
df=pd.DataFrame(product)
df.to_csv('firm.csv')
```

The data of the `website` will be down in to CSV file  as shown in pic  is I am appending the data in wrong way why is data  moving down  where I am wrong ...Kindly recommend where I am wrong there .......

[image]

I want output in these format Kindly suggest solution for these...I want output in these format as you shown below...

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append `wev` and `data` separately - you need website and name in the same dictionary for pandas to know that they belong to same row.

---

You could add the websites in a separate list like

```py
sites = []
# for url in urls:   
        # driver.get...
        # soup = ....
        # try:....except:....

        data={
                'website':website
        }
 
        sites.append(data)
```

and then [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) and [combine](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-update-method/):

```py
for pi, dictPair in enumerate(zip(product, sites)):
        product[pi].update(dictPair[1])

df = pd.DataFrame(product)
df.to_csv('firm.csv')
```

**However, I don't think it's the best way to make sure the right Names and Websites are matched up.**

---

You should just add to the same dictionary for each row from the start instead of zipping and merging.

```py
added_urls = []        
product = [] 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
details = soup.select("tbody tr")
for detail in details:

        try:        
                t1 = detail.select_one("h5.profile-title a").text
        except:
                # pass # then you'll just be using the previous row's t1
                # [also, if this happens in the first loop, it will raise an error]

                t1 = 'MISSING' # '' #
  
        wev = {
                'Name':t1,
                }

        href = detail.select_one("h5.profile-title + p a[href]") 
        if href and href.get("href", '').startswith('http'): 
                wev['page_link'] = href.get("href")
                added_urls.append(href.get("href"))
        
        product.append(wev)

### IF YOU WANT ROWS THAT CAN'T BE CONNECTED TO NAMES ###       
page_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h5.profile-title + p a")
for link in page_links:
        if href in added_urls: continue  # skip links that are already added
        href = link.get_attribute("href")

        # urls.append(href)
        added_urls.append(href)
        product.append({"page_link": href})
##########################################################
        

for pi, prod in enumerate(product): 
        if "page_link" not in prod or not prod["page_link"]: continue ## missing link
        url = prod["page_link"]
        
        driver.get(url) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
        try:
                website=soup.select_one("p.adress-info a[target='_blank']").text
        except:
                website=''
        
        del product[pi]["page_link"] ## REMOVE this line IF you want a page_link column in csv

        # data={'website':website}
        # product.append(data)
        product[pi]['website'] = website
                
df=pd.DataFrame(product)
df.to_csv('firm.csv')
```

Comment: can yu answer that also......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798528/data-are-overwritten-using-beautifulsoup