# Data are overwritten using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Try to scrape the data but data are overwrite and they will give the data of only 2 page in the csv file kindly recommend any solution for that I an waiting for your response How can I fix this? is there any way then suggest me I think due to for loop they overwrite data Thank you.these is the have already searched for an answer here and spent a long time on google, but nothing... I've already tried opening the file with 'w' instead of 'r' or 'a' but I still can't get my code to

```
from selenium import webdriver           
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import requests
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) 

url='https://mergr.com/login'

driver.get(url)

email=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#username")
email.send_keys("timgr8@outlook.com")

password=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#password")
password.send_keys("Cosmos1990$$$$$$$")

login=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.btn").click()

for page in range(1,3):
        URL = 'https://mergr.com/firms/search/employees?page={page}&firm%5BactiveInvestor%5D=2&sortColumn=employee_weight&sortDirection=asc'.format(page=page)
        driver.get(URL)


        added_urls = []        
        product=[]
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
        details = soup.select("tbody tr")
        for detail in details:

                try:        
                        t1 = detail.select_one("h5.profile-title a").text
                except:
                        # pass # then you'll just be using the previous row's t1
                        # [also, if this happens in the first loop, it will raise an error]

                        t1 = 'MISSING' # '' #
                
              
        
                wev = {
                        'Name':t1,
                        
                        }

                href = detail.select_one("h5.profile-title + p a[href]") 
                if href and href.get("href", '').startswith('http'): 
                        wev['page_link'] = href.get("href")
                        added_urls.append(href.get("href"))
                
                product.append(wev)
        
        ### IF YOU WANT ROWS THAT CAN'T BE CONNECTED TO NAMES ###       
        page_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h5.profile-title + p a")
        for link in page_links:
                if href in added_urls: continue  # skip links that are already added
                href = link.get_attribute("href")

                # urls.append(href)
                added_urls.append(href)
                product.append({"page_link": href})
        ##########################################################
                
       
        for pi, prod in enumerate(product): 
                if "page_link" not in prod or not prod["page_link"]: continue ## missing link
                url = prod["page_link"]
                
                driver.get(url) 
                soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
                try:
                        website=soup.select_one("p.adress-info a[target='_blank']").text
                except:
                        website=''
                
                del product[pi]["page_link"] ## REMOVE this line IF you want a page_link column in csv

                # data={'website':website}
                # product.append(data)
                
                product[pi]['website'] = website
        
                        
df=pd.DataFrame(product)
df.to_csv('firm.csv')
```

Comment: `for page in range(1,3)` - so that will only loop for `i=1` and `i=2`. If you want more pages, try using a larger number than `3`...

Comment: try  but they give me last page data only

Comment: Currently, you're clearing the `product` list and the beginning of each page loop - either move the `product=[]` line to *before*  `for page in range(1,3)` **OR** indent the last two lines [with append mode - `df.to_csv('firm.csv', mode='a' )`] to get then inside the page loop; i.e., **the `product=[]` line and the `df...` lines should have the SAME indent level**

Comment: (I don't recommend append mode btw, it's a bit annoying - if you use `header=False`, you won't have any headers [unless you write extra code to initialize the csv with them], but if you don't then the header row keeps getting repeated every few rows....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're clearing the `product` list at the beginning of each page loop - either move the `product=[]` line to before `for page in range(1,3)` OR indent the last two lines [with append mode - `df.to_csv('firm.csv', mode='a' )`] to get then inside the page loop; i.e., **the `product=[]` line and the `df...` lines should have the SAME indent level**.

(I don't recommend append mode btw, it's a bit annoying - if you use `header=False`, you won't have any headers [unless you write extra code to initialize the csv with them, like in `saveScrawlSess` in [this crawler](https://pastebin.com/TBtYja5D) ], but if you don't then the header row keeps getting repeated every few rows....)